# Django upload data into memory

Tags: django, memory, file-upload, django-forms, django-uploads

**Is it possible in Django to load data into the Memory, process it and return it to the User?**

Example:
User uploads image -> Python Script process it (e.g. make it s/w) -> User sees processed Image on same Webpage

(Other Examples would be all these "convert-online" sites like *pdf2doc.com*)

**Is it a bad idea to load it into the Memory?**

**Would a Queue and saving it on a CDN be a better solution?**

I'm trying to understand the possibilities of handling files from the User, which don't need to be safed. I appreciate any further ideas/considerations.

Comment: Have you checked out [this tutorial](https://dustindavis.me/django-custom-upload-handler-to-compress-image-files/)? There is also an update to the code snippet that you [can find here](https://gist.github.com/davidwtbuxton/4135069).

Comment: Thank you, this helps me further answering the first question.
So it is possible by extending the MemoryFileUploadHandler.
I'll try to implement this into a web app to have a better understanding of the   consequences.